# Am trying to implement a nested sortable ul li list but not able to

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I know that this is not straightforward but there should be some way to achieve this.

Am refering this code from JQuery:

1. http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart

Requirement is like a list with nested ul li elements with 5 levels deep (something like a hierarchial data ) and this can be moved from or to another list which could be empty or with any data.

Am not able to find how to make this nested list sortable and if done what if I move level 3 node from first list to second where the parent levels are not present in second list at all.

```
**List 1**                                                **List 2**

Root Level
   Level One 
   Level Two
      Level Two a
      Level Two b
      Level Two c
         Level Two c a
            Level Two c a a
            Level Two c a b
                Level Two c a b a
         Level Two c b
   Level Three
```

I might be even wrong in choosing nested ul li also but still not sure and stuck here.
I want to use JQtree as the last option.

This is the Fiddle link similar to Jquery Website but with nested link
http://jsfiddle.net/ErSRr/

Thank you for the suggestion. Have tried mjsarfatti but that doesnt keep track of the item from one list to another and maintain the same order as the parent one..
(i.e), I can pull even level 3 Item in second list or the fifth one. There is no limit for this.

Comment: try this https://github.com/mjsarfatti/nestedSortable

Comment: Please post a fiddle so all of your code can be looked at.